# Navigation based application in IPAD

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I could not find any Navigation Based Application template in Xcode. As of now, I am just pushing the viewControllers to the stack and then building the application. I wanted to know how can we create a navigation based application where we can set a RootViewController and add the viewControllers onto it.., So that it would be easy to add the NavigationItems to the navigation bar in every view. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tutorial for it: [Tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_a_Navigation_based_iOS_4_iPad_Application_using_TableViews_%28Xcode_4%29)

How to add this tempelate: [add template](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/ben_ellingson/2010/06/the_missing_universal_ipad_iphone_app_template)

Answer (score 2):

Apple suggest to use **split-View** based application on iPad, Read below for the iOS project types.

[Creating an iOS Application Project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/100-iOS_Development_Quick_Start/development_quick_start.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH3-SW24)

Read the blog post

[All about iPad: Resolution, UI Elements, Gestures, UX Guidelines](http://curiouxblog.wordpress.com/tag/information-hierarchy/)